Cannot Connect to Oracle Autonomous Database using Springboot and TNS wallet
I have a Autonomous database which I want to connect via Springboot but I am facing the following error even when ACL is turned off on Oracle Database.
java.sql.SQLException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12506, TNS:listener rejected connection based on service ACL filtering

My application.properties look like this -
spring.application.name=hr_data
database=oracle
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@(description= (retry_count=1)(retry_delay=3)(address=(protocol=tcps)(port=1522)(host=adb.ap-mumbai-1.oraclecloud.com))(connect_data=(service_name=123_mydb_high.adb.oraclecloud.com))(security=(ssl_server_dn_match=yes)))?TNS_ADMIN=F:/Downloads/Wallet_myDB
spring.datasource.username=ADMIN123
spring.datasource.password=123
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
#logging.level.org.springframework=DEBUG
oracle.net.tns_admin=F:/Downloads/Wallet_myDB

I am able to connect to the DB using SQL Developer studio using the Wallet which I have downloaded.
Things I have tried :-

Turning on Access control list in oracle and adding my IP - doesn't work
Trying various combination of TNS_ADMIN on connection string and oracle.net.tns_admin - doesn't work
Trying to connect via manual @Configuration class - doesn't work.
F:\Downloads\Wallet_myDB, F:/Downloads/Wallet_myDB -nope

Now I am scratching my head what else is remaining or is there some misconfiguration from my end? Any help is appreciated
ISSUE RESOLVED
The application properties should look like this-
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@(description= (retry_count=20)(retry_delay=3)(address=(protocol=tcps)(port=1522)(host=adb.ap-mumbai-1.oraclecloud.com))(connect_data=(service_name=abv_mydb_high.adb.oraclecloud.com))(security=(ssl_server_dn_match=yes)))
TNS_ADMIN=F:/Downloads/Wallet_myDB
spring.datasource.username=ADMIN123
spring.datasource.password=123


Blockquote


Is the app running on the same machine as SQL Developer? You can remove all the ACLs on the database and try again. If the error is the same, you will need to file an SR for this so they can check if anything is wrong on the database side.

@YasinB - the app is running on my desktop and the database is in cloud. Acl is disabled currently still it isn't working

ISSUE RESOLVED The application properties should look like this-
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@(description= (retry_count=20)(retry_delay=3)(address=(protocol=tcps)(port=1522)(host=adb.ap-mumbai-1.oraclecloud.com))(connect_data=(service_name=abv_mydb_high.adb.oraclecloud.com))(security=(ssl_server_dn_match=yes)))
TNS_ADMIN=F:/Downloads/Wallet_myDB
spring.datasource.username=ADMIN123
spring.datasource.password=123


Your URL can also be:
jdbc:oracle:thin:/@NAME_OF_TNSNAMES_ENTRY?TNS_ADMIN=PATH_TO_MAIN_WALLET_DIR
Your "(description= (retry_count=20)(retry_delay=3)(address=(protocol=tcps)(port=1522)(host=adb.ap-mumbai-1.oraclecloud.com))(connect_data=(service_name=abv_mydb_high.adb.oraclecloud.com))(security=(ssl_server_dn_match=yes)))" being referenced in the tnsnames.ora under the name you give in the URL.
In case you want to access several different autonomous DBs, each having its own wallet, you add "(MY_WALLET_DIRECTORY=PATH_TO_WALLET1,2,..._DIR)" after the "(ssl_server_dn_match=yes)" with each wallet expanded in its own subdirectory.
Doing so, you will have same connect string from JDBC, sqlplus, sqlcl, ... simple question of comfort...

I tried this way but this isn't working
